# Crossfilter filter based on textbox

Tags: d3.js, datatables, crossfilter, dc.js

I would like to filter my data based on the input in a textbox. Is this possible? Something like [this](http://datatables.net/release-datatables/examples/api/multi_filter.html) but with crossfilter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Certainly possible with `crossfilter`, just create `dimension` objects from your raw data and then apply a filter by the input of the text box.

```
myDimension.filter(valueFromBox); // selects values who equal the value in the text box
```

Check out the [API docs here.](https://github.com/square/crossfilter/wiki/API-Reference)