# Crossfiltering using textboxes

Tags: javascript, d3.js, dc.js

I am been googling all around but i cannot seem to find a good example on using crossfiltering with textbox.

I am trying to add a textbox filtering on a datatable using crossfilter.

Currently following this code base http://bl.ocks.org/d3noob/6077996

and reading this wiki didnt help much

https://github.com/square/crossfilter/wiki/API-Reference

I know theres a question that has been asked but the solution is too short for me to replicate it

[Crossfilter filter based on textbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15615336/crossfilter-filter-based-on-textbox)

Comment: dc.js 3.* has a [textFilterWidget](https://dc-js.github.io/dc.js/docs/html/dc.textFilterWidget.html) built-in, which may help. It's also not all that hard to implement as @matthias.rocks suggests.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure where you are at with your project, so I can only give broad advice for things you can investigate further.

- Before you can filter on a dimension with crossfilter.js, you need to register that dimension. In the example you've found, this is what is being done when the `var magValue`, `var timeDimension`, `var depthValue`, and `var volumeByDay` variables are initialized.
- If you aren't already, you need to listen for when a character is inserted into your textbox. This can be done with an event listener that listens for the [keyup](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/keyup) event. When the listener registers a keyup event, you can trigger a filter function on a corresponding dimension.
- When using the `myDimension.filter(value)` function in crossfilter.js, it filters on either exact value, a range or a function depending on whether it is passed a simple variable, and array, or a function. In the example you've found this seems to be be handled by dc.js, but in the Stack Overflow and in the API you reference this is handled manually by interacting with a pre-instantiated dimension. 
  If exact matching is what you want then you can pass the content from you textbox directly. If you want more fuzzy criteria, you can use something like [Levenshtein distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance) (e.g. via [this npm package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/levenshtein-edit-distance)) by passing a function when calling `myDimension.filter(value)`.

Let me know if this helps you (or not). If you could share the code you currently have, I can address your problem more conceretely.